# InfluxDB V1 Database Missing

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, flux-influxdb, influx-line-protocol

Due to recent restart of InfluxDB V1, I started InfluxDB service again.
When I run `show databases`, I am unable to see my database.
But in data folder, There is database named folder and autogen folder.

Please help me to link those data with the database.

Note: I tried to create new database with the same name, but it is not detecting the data folders.